# Twisted adbapi.ConnectionPool doesnt do anything

Tags: python, twisted

I try to use code below:

```
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi   

    dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool(
                        "MySQLdb",
                        db='test_db',
                        port='3306',
                        user='tester',
                        passwd='some_pass',
                        host='localhost',
                        cp_reconnect=True
                    )

    dbpool.runQuery("INSERT INTO `htp_test` VALUES(NULL, 25, 'test')")
```

But data not inserted in mysql, also no error is shown. Data to connection is well.

Comment: do you need to start the reactor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to start the reactor.  the "a" in `adbapi` is for "asynchronous", like just about everything else in twisted.  When you call `ConnectionPool.runQuery()`, you have asked twisted to do some work in the background, and when it is done, give you the result of that action in the deferred returned by `runQuery`.

But for twisted to "do" anything, you are obligated to start its event loop.  In the very simplest case, you could:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi 

def got_result(value):
    # do something, value won't be interesting on insert statements, though
    print "Horray"    
    # since this is all we want to do, stop the reactor
    reactor.stop()

d = dbpool.runQuery("INSERT INTO `htp_test` VALUES(NULL, 25, 'test')")
d.addCallback(got_result)

reactor.run()
```

Comment: I should note that you only need to do this for a short script.  In any large Twisted system or application, the reactor should already be running, if this is in the middle of some code doing something else.  The reactor should be run only once in your program.